# Density matrix of spatially (i.e., at the same time instant) vs. causally ( i.e., one evolves into the other) correlated quantum systems

Tags: quantum-state, density-matrix

In the classical case, if Y is the output of a classical channel whose input is X, it makes sense to speak of a joint distribution $P_{XY}$. In the quantum case, if a state $\rho_A$ is input to a channel $\mathcal{E}_{B|A}$ producing $\rho_B$, speaking of a quantum state $\rho_{AB}$ is not consistent. However, if A and B are spatially correlated systems, and it makes sense in that case to speak of $\rho_{AB}$. Why is that?

Comment: You might find this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.03637) interesting

Comment: Yes, that's what I am looking for, thank you.